# passing index Parameters for Flann matcher using opencv on android

Tags: android, opencv, indexing, flannbasedmatcher

I'm trying to customize the Flann matcher in opencv by editing the index parameters, but I'm using java for android, and I don't know how exactly it works.
I found this [answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/12429/matching-orb-descriptors-with-flann-lsh-on-android/?answer=12460#post-id-12460) but I don't know how to apply it in a correct way
here is the code I've tried

```
    String yamlParam="%YAML:1.0\n"
            + "indexParams:\n"
            + "   -\n"
            + "      name: algorithm\n"
            + "      type: 23\n"
            + "      value: 1\n"
            + "   -\n"
            + "      name: trees\n"
            + "      type: 4\n"
            + "      value: 4\n";

    File outputF = File.createTempFile("FlannfDetectorParams", ".YAML", outputDir);
    writeToFile(outputF,yamlParam);
    descriptorMatcher.read(outputF.getPath());
```

and here's the error I'm getting

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (sp.type() == FileNode::SEQ) in virtual void cv::FlannBasedMatcher::read(const cv::FileNode &)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the full format of the yml configuration file:

```
%YAML:1.0
---
format: 3
indexParams:
   -
      name: algorithm
      type: 23
      value: 1
   -
      name: trees
      type: 4
      value: 4
searchParams:
   -
      name: checks
      type: 4
      value: 32
   -
      name: eps
      type: 5
      value: 0.
   -
      name: sorted
      type: 15
      value: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question in Android SDK 28 and OpenCV 4.5.2.

You should use the external story use absolute path.

Comment: Well, this is not a complete answer. try elaborating your answer for better understanding.